# While loop for two queries

Tags: php, sql, xml

I have this two queries one for showing the minimum rate while the other one for showing all the rates. I'm using while loop to fetch data the first while loop is for the Property with the min and group by id and the other while loop is for the room bundles which contain all the rates.
I want to have this kind of format:

```
 <Result>
        <Property>7</Property>
        <Checkin>2015-12-27</Checkin>
        <Nights>1</Nights>
        <Baserate currency="PHP" all_inclusive="true">4000</Baserate>
        <AllowablePointsOfSale>
        <PointOfSale id="7"/>
        </AllowablePointsOfSale>

         <RoomBundle>
            <RoomID>26</RoomID>
            <Baserate currency="PHP" all_inclusive="true">4385</Baserate>
            <AllowablePointsOfSale>
            <PointOfSale id="7"/>
            </AllowablePointsOfSale>
          </RoomBundle>

          <RoomBundle>
           <RoomID>167</RoomID>
           <Baserate currency="PHP" all_inclusive="true">4000</Baserate>
           <AllowablePointsOfSale>
           <PointOfSale id="7"/>
           </AllowablePointsOfSale>
          </RoomBundle>
    </Result>
    <Result>
            <Property>9</Property>
            <Checkin>2015-12-27</Checkin>
            <Nights>1</Nights>
            <Baserate currency="PHP" all_inclusive="true">5000</Baserate>
            <AllowablePointsOfSale>
            <PointOfSale id="7"/>
            </AllowablePointsOfSale>

             <RoomBundle>
                <RoomID>2</RoomID>
                <Baserate currency="PHP" all_inclusive="true">6385</Baserate>
                <AllowablePointsOfSale>
                <PointOfSale id="7"/>
                </AllowablePointsOfSale>
              </RoomBundle>
        </Result>
```

The format I'm getting right now is all the room bundles goes to only one property. Is it possible to query it in one line? What would be the best way to get the format?Thanks

While loop

```
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) { 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result1)) { 
    $rate = $row['Minrate'];
    for ($a = 1; $a <= $Nights; ++$a) { 
        $full_rate = $rate * $a;
        $Result = $Transaction->addChild('Result');
        $Property = $Result->addChild('Property',$row['hotel_id']);
        $Checkin = $Result->addChild('Checkin', $Checkin);
        $full_rate = $rate * $a;
        $Nights1 = $Result->addChild('Nights', $a);
        $Baserate = $Result->addChild('Baserate', $full_rate);
                $Baserate -> addAttribute('currency', 'PHP');
                $Baserate -> addAttribute('all_inclusive', 'true');
        $AllowablePointsOfSale = $Result ->addChild('AllowablePointsOfSale');
            $PointOfSale = $AllowablePointsOfSale-> addChild('PointOfSale');
    $PointOfSale -> addAttribute ('id',$row['hotel_id']); }
        }
    }




            $hotelid = $row1['hotel_id'];
            $roomtypeid = $row1['roomtypeid'];
            $roomtype = $row1['roomtype'];
            $rates = $row1['rates'];
            $weekrate = $row1['$week_rate'];
            $weekmin = $row1['$week_min'];
        //for room bundles
        //$full_rate = $rates * $a;
        $RoomBundle = $Result -> addChild('RoomBundle');
            $RoomID = $RoomBundle -> addChild('RoomID', $roomtypeid);
        //$PackageID = $RoomBundle -> addChild('PackageID', 'package_id');
        $Baserate = $RoomBundle->addChild('Baserate', $rates);
                $Baserate -> addAttribute('currency', 'PHP');
                $Baserate -> addAttribute('all_inclusive', 'true');
        $AllowablePointsOfSale = $RoomBundle ->addChild('AllowablePointsOfSale');
            $PointOfSale = $AllowablePointsOfSale-> addChild('PointOfSale');
        $PointOfSale -> addAttribute ('id',$hotelid);       
}
```

SQL

```
    $sql1 = "Select roomtype.hotel_id, roomtype.roomtypeid, roomtype.week_rate, roomtype.week_min, roomtype.max_pax, roomtype.roomtype, roomtype.no_pax, 
MIN(roomtype.rates) AS Minrate, hotel.currencylab, hotel.id, room.hotelid, roomtype.rates
From roomtype, hotel, room WHERE  roomtype.hotel_id IN ($hotels) AND roomtype.deleted='0' AND  roomtype.no_pax='2' AND roomtype.hotel_id = hotel.id AND roomtype.hotel_id = room.hotelid
Group by hotel.id Order by roomtype.roomtypeid, roomtype.rates";

$sql = "Select roomtype.* ,hotel.currencylab,hotel.id From roomtype,hotel WHERE  roomtype.hotel_id IN ($hotels) AND  roomtype.deleted='0' AND roomtype.hotel_id = hotel.id";

$sql_result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
$sql_result1 = mysql_query($sql1, $conn);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code, so we can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have done.
Created an array.

```
  while($hotel_min = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result1)) {
            $rowset1[]=$hotel_min;
}
while($room = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
            $rowset2[]=$room;
}
```

Added a foreach and an if condition.

```
foreach($rowset1 as $row) {
    for ($a = 1; $a <= $Nights; ++$a) {
    $full_rate = $row['Minrate'] * $a;
        $Result = $Transaction->addChild('Result');
        $Property = $Result->addChild('Property', $row['hotel_id']);
        $Checkin = $Result->addChild('Checkin', $Checkin);
        $Nights1 = $Result->addChild('Nights', $a);
        $Baserate = $Result->addChild('Baserate', $full_rate);
                $Baserate -> addAttribute('currency', $row['currencylab']);
                $Baserate -> addAttribute('all_inclusive', 'true');
        $AllowablePointsOfSale = $Result ->addChild('AllowablePointsOfSale');
    $PointOfSale = $AllowablePointsOfSale-> addChild('PointOfSale');
    $PointOfSale -> addAttribute ('id',$row['hotel_id']);
  foreach($rowset2 as $row1) {
      if ($row['hotel_id'] == $row1['hotel_id']){
          $hotelid = $row1['hotel_id'];
            $roomtypeid = $row1['roomtypeid'];
            $roomtype = $row1['roomtype'];
            $rates = $row1['rates'];
            $weekrate = $row1['$week_rate'];
            $weekmin = $row1['$week_min'];
            $fullrate = $rates * $a;
        //for room bundles
        //$full_rate = $rates * $a;
        $RoomBundle = $Result -> addChild('RoomBundle');
            $RoomID = $RoomBundle -> addChild('RoomID', $roomtypeid);
        //$PackageID = $RoomBundle -> addChild('PackageID', 'package_id');
        $Baserate = $RoomBundle->addChild('Baserate', $fullrate);
                $Baserate -> addAttribute('currency', $row1['currencylab']);
                $Baserate -> addAttribute('all_inclusive', 'true');
        $AllowablePointsOfSale = $RoomBundle ->addChild('AllowablePointsOfSale');
            $PointOfSale = $AllowablePointsOfSale-> addChild('PointOfSale');
            $PointOfSale -> addAttribute ('id',$hotelid);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```